# Arched Relationship Infographic In Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphviz, graphic

This is a very specific inforgraphic challange altough the fundemental question is how do you build archs between words using matplotlib, cario or an other python libary.

Given a the following data structure.

me, you, 7 |
me, apple, 9 |
apple, you, 1 |
bike, me, 5

Names would be displayed horizontally the names with the most relationships larger than the others and then there would be weighted archs between the names. A 10 weighted arch would be twice as thick as a 5 weighted arch.

Inspiration comes from: similar diverstiy. http://similardiversity.net/

Let the challange commence!

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Do you need it to be vector-based for zooming/printing, or will bitmaps do? I fear that this time Matplotlib will be a little hard to stir to doing that kind of graph.

Comment: Vector based would be best I think. Yep this feels like more of a job for cario. Moved beyond the world of mathematical charting.. Any idea on how to work the text and Bezier curves/ archs to get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries, at least one of which relies on Matplotlib, that will do what you want. I recommend Networkx (www.networkx.lanl.gov) to build your graph structure, and which you can then use to call the relevant Matplotlib methods to plot. Networkx and Matplotlib work very well together.

```
import networkx as NX
import matplotlib.pyplot as PLT
Gh = NX.Graph()
Gh.add_edge("You", "Bike", weight=1.0)
Gh.add_edge("Bike", "Apple", weight=0.9)
Gh.add_edge("Me", "Bike", weight=1.1)
all_nodes = Gh.nodes()
# to scale node size with degree:
scaled_node_size = lambda(node) : NX.degree(Gh, node) * 700
position = NX.spring_layout(Gh)    # just choose a layout scheme
NX.draw_networkx_nodes(Gh, position, node_size=map(scaled_node_size, all_nodes))
NX.draw_network_edges(Gh, position, Gh.edges(), width=1.0, alpha=1.0, edge_color="red")
# now for the Matplotlib part:
PLT.axis("off")
PLT.show()
```

As you can see, you could scale the edges by applying a factor to vary the 'weight' parameter to any of the 'edge' methods, just the same way as i did it for node scaling.

I would also recommend pygraphviz (obviously using graphviz as its backend).  It is very similar to Netwworkx (same lead developer).

Answer (score 4):

`matplotlib`  isn't the right library here, since it's not a general purpose graphics library. What you need here is either something like [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/), or much simpler, you can do with the graphics capabilities of any GUI toolkit, such as PyQt. Another feasible approach is PyGame, which has good drawing capabilities as well.

If you want an example, see this [Cairo samples](http://www.cairographics.org/samples/) page, the first sample - arc. You just write the text words and then use the arc code for an arc of any width and color between them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see where the difficulty or challenge is. All you need is a graphics library that can draw text and half circles, which is possible in pretty much everything. There is no need for Bezier curves. For example you could simply create an SVG file (then you don't even need any library and can nicely embed this in a webpage and use some JavaScript to make it interactive).

The actual plotting is simple: the center of a circle is in the middle between the two words, the radius is half the distance between them. You can then adjust the stroke to reflect other quantities.

Comment: I guess I was looking for insight into what packages people recommend and what functions would be best to use. This isn't inherently difficult however finding the best package and the correct function is...

Comment: @Matt: I think there is no "best" library for this because the task is not special in any way. To decide which one is the best one for your case we would need more information about your requirements (e.g. should it be cross platform, interactive, integrated into a GUI, ...). I would probably go the SVG way, but that is just me.